# Queue Library in ARM Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I'm writing some multi-threading C++ code on the Raspberry Pi, and I need a queue, like a first in first out kind of queue like in the  library that exists on windows standard C++ libraries.  Does such a thing exist?  Googling just turns up stuff about message queues, or this http://linux.die.net/man/3/queue, and neither seem quite like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the C++ STL Queue work?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/

Comment: Thank you for the response, however the compiler gives me the error "fatal error:  queue:  No such file or directory" whenever I attempt to include (#include <queue>) any STL libraries.  I thought STL was mostly a windows standard and Linux did their own shtick.  If I have to make my own I'll do so, but I don't want to if there is some obscure library or I'm just retarded at googling.

Comment: STL is a part of C++, which works fine on Linux. What complier are you trying to use? g++?

Comment: Thanks to your comment I found my problem.  I'm using Geany to compile on the Pi, and did not realize that its default makefile uses gcc without linking to the standard library.  I feel silly, but thank you.

Comment: All good. Happens to the best of us. Do you want to accept the answer, since we got it all sorted out?